# How to create a list containing Switch components

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to create a UI with a list of Container elements containing Label and Switch components. In 2015 I did something similar using a ContainerList.

Apparently Codename One recommends using a Container instead. I refer to the blog entry [Avoiding Lists](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html) which recommends using a scrollable BoxLayout.Y_AXIS container.

But I'm having trouble with that because I want to enable manual sorting of the elements of the container that represents a list. Manual sorting would be done via long press on one of the elements to initiate dragging. This even works when setting setFocusable(true) on  the list entry containers. But then the components contained in the list entry containers don't receive any pointer events. And if I don't set the attribute setFocusable(true) the container doesn't receive pointer events. Also just redirecting the pointer event methods to preserve standard behaviour doesn't work because that would lead to recursion.

How would one create a proper list of containers containing UI-elements where scrolling still works, where some pointer events are handled by the list entry containers and the entries UI-elements also work as intended?

Imagine this structure:

Container with BoxLayout.Y containing
    n containers with BoderLayout containing Label and Switch components

- Scrolling should work dragging vertically on any list entry location
- Tapping of dragging the Switch component contained in any entry container should still work as intended

Comment: How would the UI differentiate between dragging and scrolling? 
Normally when you have a UI like that the app has a toggle for "edit mode" which allows you to drag the elements. Then when you're done dragging you return to standard scrolling mode

Comment: Yes - it works, just as described. See my app from 2015 based on ContainerList - https://gofile.io/?c=TwYsZq

Comment: The trouble seems to be that pointer events are either processed by a child component of by its container and for fluent operation it is sometimes requires that both handle the events. But if the child components would behave well and call the super pointer methods this would work if I am right. So it seems to be that the Codename One components like Button or Switch should be fixed in that regard.

Comment: Derive them and call the parent yourself if you think that's wrong

Comment: But deriving and calling the parent myself is impossible. And I still find it hard to believe that something as basic as that should be hard to do - I mean the first question. How about You think about that? Shouldn’t it be a very easy thing to do? A list, scrollable, entries draggable and UI components in the entries that just work

Comment: You filed several issues on this, we didn't close them other than the duplicate. That means we'll give it some thought when we get a chance.